# insert into table from other table but new values except id

Tags: mysql

So i want to insert new values in table2 with the same id as table 1.

i cannot use LAST_INSERT_ID() because the values that come inside table2 can be added later.

a little view of my tables
table1

```
id    | forum_name |  password 
-------------------------------
1     Bob Barker    lol123
```

table2

```
id    | in_game_name 
------------------
1     Bob_Barker
```

i've looked up some information, but some say mysql doesn't support that,
i don't know if thats true but i didn't came up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In table terms it is not clear why the second table is required.  If the member has an in game name then why can't this be put in table1.  More context may be required before this can be answered.

So it looks like you need 3 tables.

Table 1: people
Table 2: games
Table 3: people in games.

Table 3 has two foreign keys, one pointing at table 1 and the other at table 2.  It has a column for the name in the game.

This is a many to many relationship.

Comment: because table2 is a one game, there's gonna be a table3, table4 and on and on, and the tables are like a storage place for stats in the game

Comment: Sorry but that table design breaks normal forms badly.  You need three tables here: 1 = people, 2 = games, 3 = peoples names in games.  This is a classic many to many relationship where many people can play many games and they can have a different name in each game.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE forum_name="Bob Barker" and password="lol123"` before inserting the new row in table2.

Comment: Yes, I would think the person whose "game name" is being added had logged in, so their user id should already be known.